# JavaScript in MVC 5 not being read?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm still learning MVC and I wanted to find a way to set focus on a textbox when a view loads. I found a suggestion to add the following to the _Layout.cshtml page so it would set focus to the first textbox on each page. However, it doesn't seem to be working.

I'm thinking it has to do with the fact that I have the default @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") set and so it ignores any JS code set directly in the page.

This is the first thing I tried in the _Layout page:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {       
        // Set the focus to the first textbox on every form in the app
        $("input[type=text]").first().focus();
    });
    </script>

</head>
```

Then I tried creating a file called Scripts/app.js and added that to the bottom of the Bundle.Congif.cs file. That didn't work either.

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/appScript").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/app.js*"));
        }
```

app.js (no `<script>` at the top of the file)

```
$(function () {
    // Set the focus to the first textbox on every form in the app
    $("input[type=text]").first().focus();
});
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE with fix**

Just for clarity this is how I got it to work from @Shyju suggestions. I left the addition of my Scripts/app.js in the BundleConfig.cs like I have above. Then in the Layout.cshtml page where I already had bundle references I just add the render to my added bundle which I called appScipt.

This is in my Layout.cshtml file:

```
<div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/appScript")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include this new bundle in the specific page/view where you want to have the focus on the textbox.

```
@section Scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/appScript")
}
```

Or you can directly refer the file instead of using the bundle (if you do not wish to take the advantages of bundling).

```
@section Scripts
{
   <script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
}
```

And make sure you have `RenderSection` in your Layout so that it will include  the page specific script when razor render the page ( with layout)

```
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") 
</head>
<body>
     <div id="pageContent">
        @RenderBody()
     </div>
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
     @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Comment: So you're saying I need to go the route of having the app.js set in my BundleConfig.cs like I did. Then I need to add the Scripts.Render on every view that I want to set focus? Or, I can set the BundleConfig.cs and then put the RenderSection at the top of my Layout page?

Comment: It is not necessary that you need to use the bundle. You can simply refer the js file directly. Using the bundle will give you the benefits of bundling(saving you bandwidth). You need to have the `@RenderSection` method only in the Layout. See my updated answer.

Comment: Got it. I have to quit working on this for the time being but I'll get it a try and let you know how it goes. Thanks.